# is it possible to explicit set an counter for my `Pos`-Property?

Tags: c#

is it possible to explicit set an counter for my `Pos`-Property ?

```
    public class SomeClass
    {
        public List<SomeData> Data { get; set; }
    }

    public class SomeData
    {
        private int _pos;

        public int Pos
        {
            get { return _pos; }
            private set { _pos = value; }
        }

    }
```

Calling the code:

```
SomeClass hasAlreadySomeData=new SomeData();

foreach(item in hasAlreadySomeData.Data)
{
Console.Writeline("Data with Position: " + item.Pos);
}


This should result in:
```

> "Data with Position: 1"     "Data with Position: 2"     "Data with
>   Position: 3"  ...

Without explicit setting the Pos(it shall be an counter for the element in that List)

Comment: Why not a regular for loop over the Data.Count? Then you have the numeric index of each item. . .

Comment: You'd need to write your own List-wrapper, which would set the "Pos" field on SomeData before it added to the actual list. -- *somewhere* you need to manually tack the position of elements you add/remove ass you add them to `SomeClass`'s List

Comment: That's what the `IndexOf` method is for. Some will say it is not the job of an object to know what it's position is in a collection. I would agree. What happens when the same object is in multiple collections?

Comment: @TyCobb , thank you ,you are right.

Answer (score 0):

You already know how many items are in the List. Just loop over it:

```
for (int pos = 0; pos < Data.Count; ++pos) {
    Console.Writeline("Data with Position: " + pos);
}
```

If you want your position to be 1-indexed, then:

```
for (int pos = 0; pos < Data.Count; ++pos) {
    Console.Writeline("Data with Position: " + pos + 1);
}
```